# UIButton state selected

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, state

I've seen a lot of info on changing the button image for selected but being a new I'm having a bit of trouble implementing a simpler version of it.

When the button is pressed it goes dark and I would like it to stay that way once it's been selected. So there are a few questions.

Do I create IBOutlet for the button and then and IBAction to change the state with something like button.state = SELECTED.

Sorry for the complete lack of any code to look at.

Edit: (id)sender is the button object right?

```
-(IBAction)journalEntryViewControllerClick: (id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (id)sender;

    [button setSelected:YES];   

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set separate image for button's selected state (UIControlStateSelected) and in button action you can toggle its state:

```
- (void) btnAction:(UIButton*)button{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

Comment: sure, but simpler code may be easier to understand later if you're not used to using xor

Answer (score 2):

Yes that could be one way of doing it. If you want a "stateswitch" kind of look.

However you set the `button.selected = YES;`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a `UISegmentedControl` instead. `UIButton`'s are meant to be momentary.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that but I have images on all the buttons in a scroll view and UISegemntedControl didn't seem like a good fit.  Good to know that fact about UIButton though.  Thanks!