# Swift - ios - creating ballon buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a set of buttons that will look like this: 
(The selected buttons are those with a different background)
[image]

Any ideas for a simple implementation? 
Are there any known open source implementations for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define the rules for the appearance of  these buttons? For example it seems there should be maximum three buttons in a row. Can you specify more ?

Comment: Are you want to create like wise image https://raw.githubusercontent.com/remirobert/RRTagController/master/source/anim.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the library which may be use to solve your problem,

For different appearance you need to give the conditional code for that but with out that your problem may solve with this library or code.

You can download the sample code of [RRTagController](https://github.com/remirobert/RRTagController) project here.

Comment: @user2153912 Yes this sample code uses the UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

For rounded corners use `UIButton.layer.cornerRadius`. if you set corner radius to half of the box you will get circle. For the border color use `layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor`.

For the background color of the button you can keep track with selected state of the button. Here is an example of using selected state: [UIButton state selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635947/uibutton-state-selected)

Next thing you could do is to keep data about selected ones, since the best way to do something like this would be UITableView - seems like every row of buttons have same height, and if you want to send that somewhere you can keep track about what items are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use `UICollectionView`.